# Using 4 components in Principle Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I don't know how to interpret the output of Principle Components Analysis (PCA) and the cumulative sum graph.

I have the following problem. I have 4 machines (A, B, C, and D), and each machine has 9 features where measurements were taken along the time. The goal is to classify the machine behavior.

I am using Principle Components Analysis to reduce the dimensionality from 9 features. By reducing the dimensionality of the original feature space by projecting it onto a smaller subspace, and then plotting the cumulative sum over all the variance, you can see that the first 4 eigenvalues correspond to approximately 82% of all variance [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPP8U.png). It means that there is 18% of information being lost with the dimensionality reduction.

I want to cluster machines based on the Principal Components, but the examples that I find always plot the data using 2 Principal components (PCs) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FKqV.png). The [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FKqV.png) is the graph that I plot using just 2 PCs.

If the cumulative sum graph suggests that 4 PCs corresponds to 82% of all variance, and the examples of PCA only have 2 PCs, what should I do? Do I apply PCA a second time? Or I need to do something else that I don't know?

In [3] I show the code that I have to use PCA with 2 components and plot the graph. The A, B, C, and D are the machines.

[image]

[image]

[3]

```
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
Y_sklearn = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(X_std)

data = []

for name, col in zip(machine_list, colors.values()):

    trace = dict(
        type='scatter',
        x=Y_sklearn[y==name,0],
        y=Y_sklearn[y==name,1],
        mode='markers',
        name=name,
        marker=dict(
            color=col,
            size=12,
            line=dict(
                color='rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
                width=0.5),
            opacity=0.8)
    )
    data.append(trace)

layout = dict(
        xaxis=dict(title='PC1', showline=False),
        yaxis=dict(title='PC2', showline=False)
)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: What are you planning to use that data for? I.e., is it simply for a simplified view/feature engineering in another ML algorithm, or do you plan on explaining your concept visually with the PCA outputs?

Comment: @dennlinger the goal is to categorize machines according to the features so that I could say in the end which machine is behaving the best or the worst. Maybe I need to apply another model on the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. But I am not sure.